# Checking for a client disconnect on a Java TCP server - output only

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a Java TCP server which, when a client connects to it, outputs a message to the client every 30 seconds. It is a strict requirement that the client does not send any messages to the server, and that the server does not send any data other than the 30-second interval messages to the client.

When I disconnect the client, the server will not realise this until the next time it tries to write to the client. So it can take up to 30 seconds for the server to recognise the disconnect.

What I want to do is check for the disconnect every few seconds without having to wait, but I am not sure how to do this given that a) the server does not receive from the client and b) the server cannot send any other data. Would anyone please be able to shed some light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though your server doesn't "receive" from the client, a non-blocking read on the client socket will tell you that either there's nothing to be read (as you expect), or that the client has disconnected.

If you're using NIO you can simply use a non-blocking `Selector` loop (with non-blocking sockets) and only write on your 30 second marks. If a `SelectionKey` is readable and the read on the `SocketChannel` returns -1 you know the client has disconnected.

**EDIT:** Another approach with blocking is simply to select with a 30 second timeout. Any client disconnects will cause the select to return and you'll know which ones those are via the read set. The additional thing you'd need to do there is track how long you were blocked in the select to figure out when to do your writes on the 30 second mark (Setting the timeout for the next select to the delta).

**Big Edit:** After talking to Myn below, offering complete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Set a 1 second timeout on the socket
    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    long myNextOutputTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 30000;

    String inputLine = null;
    boolean connected = true;
    while (connected)
    {
        try {
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            if (inputLine == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Client Disconnected!");
                connected = false;
            }
        }
        catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Timed out trying to read from socket");
        }

        if (connected && (System.currentTimeMillis() - myNextOutputTime > 0))
        {
            out.println("My Message to the client");
            myNextOutputTime += 30000;
        }


    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}
```

Worth noting here is that the `PrintWriter` really moves you far away from the actual socket, and you're not going to catch the socket disconnect on the write (It will never throw an exception, you have to manually check it with `checkError()`) You could change to using a `BufferedWriter` instead (requires using `flush()` to push the output) and handling it like the `BufferedReader` to catch a disco on the write.

Comment: +1 Or, to put it another way, you have to poll, say once a second, with a non-blocking read.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I'm not using NIO, is it still possible to use a non-blocking read? I have also tried using `setSoTimeout()` but this doesn't seem to work when I force the client to close, which is one of my tests.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using NIO? It's been available since 2002 and really makes your problem trivial. I hadn't thought about how we had to do this prior to NIO in a long time; looking it up there wasn't a true non-blocking read prior to that or a `select()`. You're on the right track with `setSoTimeout()` because that's the only avenue you have. You should be able to call that prior to reading from your socket, and it'll throw an `InterruptedIOException` if it times out. Rather messy though - if you can use NIO I can give you an example of how it works.

Comment: And are you handling multiple socket connections to your server, or just one?

Comment: Oops, it actually throws a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`, just tried it.

Comment: Eh, I wanted to walk down memory lane. The edited post gives you a working example of what you're trying to do. This of course is very simple and only deals with one connected client, but it should point you in the right direction if you need more. You really should look at NIO though as it gives you lower access to the system IO.

Comment: Thanks again Brian; there is a reason I'm not using NIO but it's to do with a bizarre system requirement I've been landed with. I'm actually out of the office now for a few weeks so I can't test this, but it looks a lot like something I was trying to get working before I went home today with `BufferedReader`; your answer has really helped a lot there and I really do appreciate all you've posted, so thank you very much once more!

Answer (score 1):

If you are managing multiple clients then I guess you would be using Non-Blocking sockets (If not then consider using Non-Blocking). You can use Selector to monitor all the connected sockets to check if they are readable or writeable or there is some Error on that socket. When some client disconnects, your Selector will mark that socket and will return.
For more help google "Socket Select function"